metadata error on tif to pmtiles conversion
I like to convert tif file to pmtiles. According to this: https://github.com/protomaps/PMTiles/blob/main/README.md
I should first create mbtiles and then do conversion to pmtiles but while doing so I receive key err as shown below the code.
import os
from osgeo import gdal
from pmtiles.convert import mbtiles_to_pmtiles

input_tif = "input/xtif"
intermediate_mbtiles = "output/x.mbtiles"
output_pmtiles = "output/x.pmtiles"
options = gdal.TranslateOptions(
    format="MBTiles",
    creationOptions=["ZLEVEL=9"],
)

# tif to mbtiles
result = gdal.Translate(intermediate_mbtiles, input_tif, options=options)

# mbtiles to pmtiles
mbtiles_to_pmtiles(result, output_pmtiles, 18)

The error I got:

File "/app/main.py", line 42, in 
convert_mbtiles_to_pmtiles(intermediate_mbtiles, output_pmtiles, maxzoom=18)   File "/app/main.py", line 19, in
convert_mbtiles_to_pmtiles
mbtiles_to_pmtiles(input_mbtiles, output_pmtiles, maxzoom)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/pmtiles/convert.py", line 87,
in mbtiles_to_pmtiles
pmtiles_header, pmtiles_metadata = mbtiles_to_header_json(mbtiles_metadata)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/pmtiles/convert.py", line 24,
in mbtiles_to_header_json
center = mbtiles_metadata["center"].split(",")
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^ KeyError: 'center'

any sugestions are very welcome!

I suggest you make sure that the mbtiles metadata contains a "center" key.
